# PHP files open blank on my website on a linux system

Tags: php, apache, cpanel

I just finished working on a site. Everything is working fine on the local server but the page won't open if I use `index.php` on a live server. `index.html` does work on the live server but all the PHP code enclosed in `<?php        ?>` are displayed as-is instead of running.

My site is hosted at Linux Hosting with cPanel and I have uploaded my files via FileZilla to the web root (public_html/www) folder.

Connection to the database is

```
<?php 
   require_once('Conn\connection.php');
?>

 HTML and embeded PHP goes here...
```

This works fine on WAMP.

Comment: Can you show us your `DirectoryIndex` directive?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by `DirectoryIndex`. And how do I get it?

Comment: If you don't know what `DirectoryIndex` is, then reading [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html) might be a good start. The directive allows you to specify a default page to display when a directory is accessed.

Comment: I am on it but how could it stop from running **PHP** files as well. It is not just the home page. All the **PHP** are blank.

Comment: Try "view source" on the PHP pages that you believe to be blank. Chances are they're not blank, but just don't render HTML - as you say in your question, they are full of unprocessed PHP code. If this description is correct, look at your server control panels - perhaps PHP is not enabled. You could get in touch with your host about this, too.

Comment: @halfer: Have just done that and there is no any `html` code there. It is blank as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aha! Try this instead:

```
require_once 'Conn/connection.php';
```

The backslash is invalid on Linux systems, but will work fine on Windows. Switching to the forward slash should work on both. My guess is that your program is exiting early with a fatal error, and if you check your web server logs, you'll see the problem.

Also, since `require_once` is a keyword, I tend to use it without brackets, even though brackets will work. There are circumstances in which calling it in a function context is necessary, but this isn't one of them.

Comment: Wow! This works! Just having a connection error but do you have any idea how I can get my connection string?

Comment: @Yax, that sounds like a very different problem. We like to separate questions out here, so would you mind asking a new one? Glad this worked though!

Comment: Thanks for the assist. I should be able to find my around it. Once again, your answer was productive to me, thanks.